# Por que esta estrutura de repetição que deveria voltar uma palavra ao contrário não volta nada?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
phrase = str(input("Type your phrase: ")).upper().strip()
words_phrase = phrase.split()
words_together = ''.join(words_phrase)
phrase_inverse = ""
for letra in range(len(words_together) - 1, -1, -1):
    phrase_inverse = words_together[letra]
print(phrase_inverse)
if words_together == phrase_inverse:
    print("Esta frase é um palíndromo")
else:
    print("Não é um palíndromo")
```

Este programa tinha a finalidade de fazer uma frase ficar ao contrário, mas quando eu executo o código e o programa tenta mostrar a frase ao contrário ele só retorna a primeira letra, sendo que a phrase_inverse tá dentro do loop, seria mais fácil deixar:

```
phrase_inverse = words_together[letra:]
```

Mas o exercício não permite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na linha que você inverte a palavra:

```
phrase_inverse = words_together[letra]
```

Perceba que você sempre atribui o valor da última letra lida na variável, porém não acumula os valores, com isso você acaba tendo no final somente a primeira letra da frase digitada.

---

Para corrigir isso, basta acumular as letras durante a inversão, isso pode ser feito utilizando `+=` que concatena o valor já presente da variável com o novo inserido:

```
phrase_inverse += words_together[letra]
```

---

O código completo ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
phrase = input("Type your phrase: ").upper().strip()
words_phrase = phrase.split()
words_together = "".join(words_phrase)
phrase_inverse = ""

for letra in range(len(words_together) - 1, -1, -1):
    phrase_inverse += words_together[letra]

if words_together == phrase_inverse:
    print("Esta frase é um palíndromo")
else:
    print("Não é um palíndromo")
```

*Obs.: Perceba que remove o `str` da função input, isso porque a função input já retorna uma string, portanto não é necessária essa conversão*

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/BelatedMeanWordprocessing